# Check if class implements interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Here is an example:

There are a basic class(A) which handles lots of different classes (lets say B,C,D all extending P). In class A I need to call a function like:

```
 public void doSmth(P variable) {
      B b = (B)variable;
      b.getSomeImportantInfo();
 }
```

For this I am trying to add an interface (I) and define B, C, D implement it.

The trouble is, that doSmth will work with all this classes (B,C,D) and I dont want all of them implement this interface. So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
 public void doSmth(P variable) {
      if(variable instanceof I) {
           ((I)variable).getSomeImportantInfo();
      }
 }
```

But this does not work, cause it says it cant cast variable to I.

How can I achieve needed behavior? Also, I can not modify P and make it implement I.

Comment: That should be fine (assuming `P` is some reasonable type) - please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post short program... I''m working with android and I got an activity which handles multiple custom fragments extending Fragment class. In the activity I got private variable Class<? extends Fragment> currentFragment. and I'm trying to check whether it implements a specified interface or not. Example: public class ContentFragment extends Fragments implements Stackable. I just dont want to make all my fragments implement it and I cant make Fragment class implement it neither.

Answer (score 0):

I think it too later, but:

```
public static boolean isImplementsInterface(Class interfaze, Class clazz) {
    for (Class c : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
        if (c.equals(interfaze)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isImplementsInterface(CharSequence.class, String.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to explicitly typecast the variable to I.
Once you checked if it is instance of 'I', directly call the method and let the program decide at runtime..which will be invoked depending upon the actual object, reference variable refers.